# porque si no tiene errores, no muestra nada la consola con esta consulta JSON en el html

Tags: jquery, json, geolocalización

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var latit;
    var long;
    var kTemp;

  var ip = 'http://ip-api.com/json';
      $.getJSON(ip, function(data){
       latit = data.lat;
       long = data.lon;
       });

  //create API with geolocation
        var api = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + latit + '&lon='+ long + '&appid=XXXXxxxxxXXXXxXXXXXXxxx';
    $.getJSON(api, function(data){
  //JSon call for OpenWather API 
    var weatherType = data.weather[0].description;
      kTemp = data.main.temp;
      var winSpeed = data.wind.speed;
      var city = data.name;

      console.log(city);
      console.log(api);
      $("#city").html(city);
      $("#weatherType").html(weatherType);
      $("#winSpeed").html(winSpeed);
      $("#kTemp").html(kTemp);
});

});
```

Comment: sigo revisando pero al parecer es que no se trae data del ip-api.com ._.

Comment: ¿Estás poniendo un appId correcto? Ejemplo: `http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1`

Comment: al revisar la consola del browser me dice que el valor latid y long son undefined, crei que era que no se esta trayendo data del ip-api.com pero probando con los alert pues si la trae no se si es un error de espacios o comillas, si el id es correcto solo que no lo coloque en este codigo para tenerlo reservado

Comment: este es el error interno del api; {"cod":"400","message":"{vlat} is not a float"} ._.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que mover la segunda getJSON adentro del resultado del primero. JSON es asnychronous.
Estas llamando el segundo antes de popular los variables

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var latit;
    var long;
    var kTemp;

    var ip = 'http://ip-api.com/json';
    $.getJSON(ip, function(data){
       latit = data.lat;
       long = data.lon;

        //create API with geolocation
        var api = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + latit + '&lon='+ long + '&appid=XXXXxxxxxXXXXxXXXXXXxxx';
        $.getJSON(api, function(data){
            //JSon call for OpenWather API 
            var weatherType = data.weather[0].description;
            kTemp = data.main.temp;
            var winSpeed = data.wind.speed;
            var city = data.name;

            console.log(city);
            console.log(api);
            $("#city").html(city);
            $("#weatherType").html(weatherType);
            $("#winSpeed").html(winSpeed);
            $("#kTemp").html(kTemp);
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Ésto debería ser un comentario, o en su defecto debería ser una respuesta mas amplia

Comment: muchas gracias tiene sentido, aunque se trae el valor de la data estoy cerrando el getJSON primero y esto quiere decir que las dos funciones quedan separadas, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Las llamadas son asíncronas y cada llamada tiene que ser encadenada una tras otra. Es decir, tienes que esperar a que se descargue tu petición de los servidores, de lo contrario tus variables no tendrán nada asignado. Imagina que quieres sacar dinero de tu cuenta de ahorros y para ello vas al banco y se te olvida la tarjeta de débito, el banco no puede resolver tu petición de dinero porque no tienes la tarjeta, llamas a casa para que te lleven la dichosa tarjeta y cuando la tienes el banco te atiende.
Y deberías considerar separar tú código. Ya lo decía Sun Tzu en el arte de la guerra

> divide y vencerás

```
$(function(){
    var lat, lng, kTemp;
    var ip = 'http://ip-api.com/json';
    $.getJSON(ip, function(data){
        getWeather(data);
    });


    function getWeather(data){
        lat = data.lat;
        lng = data.lon;

        var api = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon='+ lng + '&appid=XXXXxxxxxXXXXxXXXXXXxxx';

        $.getJSON(api, function(dataFromAPI){
            createView(dataFromAPI);
        });
    }

    function createView(dataFromAPI){
        var weatherType = dataFromAPI.weather[0].description;
        var winSpeed = dataFromAPI.wind.speed;
        var city = dataFromAPI.name;
        kTemp = dataFromAPI.main.temp;
        console.log(city);
        console.log(api);
        $("#city").html(city);
        $("#weatherType").html(weatherType);
        $("#winSpeed").html(winSpeed);
        $("#kTemp").html(kTemp);
    }
});
```